Run `go-mssqldb` and GORM at the same time
I have the legacy code that written with RAW query that already contains 700+ unique queries. The system is keep growing, but I feel writing RAW query everytime through database/sql are killing our time, thus the idea to bring ORM is come. The queries also is not complex, 80% queries are CRUD operation & simple join with several table.
Now, I am trying to bring GORM but there's obstacle:
panic: sql: Register called twice for driver mssql

goroutine 1 [running]:
database/sql.Register({0x100ae634f, 0x5}, {0x100cbf740, 0x100e95f30})
        /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.22.2/libexec/src/database/sql/sql.go:51 +0x12c
github.com/microsoft/go-mssqldb.init.1()
        /Users/plabs.id/go/pkg/mod/github.com/microsoft/go-mssqldb@v1.6.0/mssql.go:37 +0x38

I also tried with minimalist code and still throw the same error:
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "log"

    _ "github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb"
    "gorm.io/driver/sqlserver"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

func main() {
    // Database connection string
    connString := "sqlserver://username:password@localhost:1433?database=yourdbname"

    // Using database/sql
    sqlDB, err := sql.Open("sqlserver", connString)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error creating connection pool: ", err.Error())
    }
    defer sqlDB.Close()

    // Using GORM
    _, err = gorm.Open(sqlserver.Open(connString), &gorm.Config{})

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error connecting to database with GORM: ", err.Error())
    }

}

A solution to resolve an error

I'm no go expert, does it help to remove  _ "github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb"
and keep only "gorm.io/driver/sqlserver"
